# \titleformat: Rule the underline

Tags: formatting, rules

I modified \section format to add an underline. How can I reduce the space between the section name and the underline? The code I used is the following.

```
\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows creating custom \section's

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `raisebox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `titlerule` and `vspace` :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\vspace{1cm}\titlerule[1pt]}]

\begin{document}
\section{TEST}
Bla bla

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\vspace{0cm}\titlerule[1pt]}]
\section{TEST2}
Bla bla2

\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\section{TEST2}
Bla bla3

\end{document}
```

[image]